# Python subclasses calling parent function

Tags: python

```
class A():
    class B():
       def Foo(self):
           print "Hello"
    class C():
       def Bar(self):
           print "Goodbye"
    def name(self):
        print "FooBar"
```

What I want to do is, within the Bar function is call the Foo function. How would I do that?

Comment: Which instance of `A`? There isn't an implicit one.

Comment: I think you may be misusing the class construct. Why would you want to do this? Have you tried inheritance?

Comment: Your classes should all inherit from `object` (e.g. `class A(object):`), so that you use [new style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).  In addition, you more than likely want `B` and `C` to inherit from A (e.g. `class B(A):`).  Doing both of these, you could then do `super(C, self).name)()`.  If this is what you want, you do not need to have `B` and `C` defined inside A.

Comment: Thanks, but turns out what I don't need subclasses or inheritince, each class(B,C,D..Z) was meant to be a thread, with A managing them, so all i need to do is make them independent, and when i call them from A __init__(self,A) then self.A=A and i  can access A's PriorityQueue's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, inner classes don't have an implicit instance of the outer class associated with them. Without such an instance, you can't call `A`'s non-static methods from `B` or `C`.

If you do have such an instance, then simply use the dot notation:

```
class C():
   def Bar(self):
       self.a.name()
   ...
```

(where `self.a` is an instance of `A`.)

Alternatively, if `A.name()` can be made static, the following will also work:

```
class A(object):

    class C():
       def Bar(self):
           print "Goodbye"
           A.name()

    @staticmethod
    def name():
        print "FooBar"

A.C().Bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of class `A` to call a method.